# Does getstream.io support multiple groups with multiple channels per group

Tags: getstream-io, getstream-chat

Does GetStream.io support the following use case:

The app needs to support groups of users.

Users can be members of one or more groups.

Groups can be public or private.
Users can be invited to private groups by group admin.

Users can join public groups without invitation.

Each group has multiple channels.
Channels can be public (anyone in the group can join) or private (invite by group admin).

Users can chat 1 to 1 or 1 to many after accepting a friend request.